# Read data from XML having nested inconsistent structure

Tags: xml, powershell

Source XML Data -

```
<EntityType Name="WorkItem">
   <Property Name="WorkItemId" Type="Edm.Int32" Nullable="false">
      <Annotation Term="Ref.ReferenceName" String="System.Id" />
      <Annotation Term="Display.DisplayName" String="Work Item Id" />
   </Property>
   <Property Name="InProgressDate" Type="Edm.DateTimeOffset">
      <Annotation Term="Display.DisplayName" String="InProgress Date" />
   </Property>
   <Property Name="InProgressDateSK" Type="Edm.Int32" />
   <Property Name="CompletedDateSK" Type="Edm.Int32" />
</EntityType>
```

Required output something like below or at least in column format. Its ok if the output is not in exact below format with headers as shown but looking for help in tweaking the code to get result in column format

[image]

What I tried -

```
Select-Xml -Path D:\Temp\meta.xml -XPath '/EntityType/Property' | ForEach-Object { $_.Node.Name, $_.Node.Type, $_.node.Annotation }
```

also

```
Select-Xml -Path D:\Temp\meta.xml -XPath '/EntityType/Property' | select -ExpandProperty Node
```

Comment: Cool. But what are you asking us?

Comment: Asking for help in getting the result as I showed in required output

Comment: Oh, OK. Can you please let us know what's working and what's not with you current approaches to help us work out what to do? The more work you put in the more likely you're going to get good answers. Good quality questions usually get answer within 15 minutes. Perhaps read [ask] to help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I would find whomever designed that XML schema and hit them with a XML how-to book. This is a horrible schema design.

Second, I'd probably process the XML like below. Convert the file to an XML document and then walk through each node. We have to keep track of the annotation columns because of the way that Powershell outputs object properties.

```
# Get the XML file as a raw string, and then convert it to an XML Document with the [xml] type accellerator
[xml]$xml = Get-Content D:\Temp\meta.xml -Raw

# This is for tracking the columns we use. These two columns are always present
$Columns = 'Name', 'Type'

$Results = foreach ($node in $xml.EntityType.Property) {
    # Create a hashtable with a key and value for each column
    $Record = @{
        Name = $node.Name
        Type = $node.Type
    }

    # Add a key and value for each column from the annotation
    foreach ($Annotation in $node.Annotation) {
        $Record[$Annotation.Term] = $Annotation.String

        # If we haven't seen this column before, note it so we can output it later
        if ($Annotation.Term -notin $Columns) {
            $Columns += $Annotation.Term
        }
    }

    # Convert the hashtable record to a custom object and save them all to results
    [PSCustomObject]$Record
}

# Output the results using the dynamic list of columns we found
$Results | Select-Object -Property $Columns
```

That gets me the output:

```
Name             Type               Ref.ReferenceName Display.DisplayName
----             ----               ----------------- -------------------
WorkItemId       Edm.Int32          System.Id         Work Item Id
InProgressDate   Edm.DateTimeOffset                   InProgress Date
InProgressDateSK Edm.Int32
CompletedDateSK  Edm.Int32
```

Comment: Can you recommend me a xml how to book?

Comment: @AbrahamZinala My books are all long gone, I'm afraid. O'Reilly is a good starting spot as always. My comment here was prompted by the fact that the designer put data into attributes and the element names are very generic, resulting in difficult to understand XML. IMO, you should avoid attributes in XML in favor of child elements, which are more flexible, and reserve attributes for metadata. XML data files should not look like XSD files.